# Simplify Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

\$A \overline C+ABC+A\overline BC=X\$ 
I dont understand how to implement the laws.
For example the law A*A'=0 , can i use it for AC'?
Then the other law A*(B+C)=A*B + A*C, i can use it for ABC?
AC'+ABC+AB'C=X //A*A'=0//
0 + (AB + AC) + (AB' + AC) =X //A*(B+C)=A*B + A*C//
Then i dont know, i can use the law A*B=B*A or the law 
A*A'=0 but i dont know if its a law exclusively for A

The answer is supposingly to be X=A
This is not homework

Comment: 1) It's not clear what is written there. What is this `NOT`? 2) This is your homework, we are not solving homeworks when no effort shown. 3) There are numerous ways to do this. Start by drawing truth table.

Comment: @EugeneSh., what does 'draw truth table' mean? Why don't you give decent guidance you're trying to help and not comment if you aren't. Lead by example and show some effort.

Comment: IMHO This is very simple, like from basic school mathematics. Really. Just apply this simple rule: (A AND NOT B) OR (A AND B) --> A

Comment: @TonyM  Truth table is a basic concept for anyone dealing with boolean logic and easily googlable. I find your comment much less constructive than mine. Guide the OP if you wish, not me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is just saying `'` means `NOT`, it's just not formatted well.

Comment: @DigitalNinja Yes. Just approved this edit..

Comment: That's a math question.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Commenting's optional, you don't have to bark at people struggling. Anyway no need, Al Kepp's stepped in for you.

Comment: @TonyM - I think both you and Eugene have good intentions. OP didn't show any work. Eugene explained that effort must be given for answers to be given, and then guided OP by suggesting a truth table. It seems you are "barking" much louder at Eugene, who again was using constructive criticism. Moral of the story here is that not all criticism is bad.

Comment: @Bort, it's in the nature of this site. Folks want to help but get frustrated at questions they feel are wasting their time. I feel that way too sometimes... but generally, just move along. The only one wasting my time.. is me.

Comment: @Bort, thanks for good observations and I'm certainly barking more at Eugene Sh - OP's an innocent newcomer to be helped and encouraged whereas ES should know better. Guide...or go off and make the tea :-) Everyone's points made, thanks again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because HW without an attempt at a solution

Comment: Jumper if that was standard Algebra would you know how to do it? If not... walk away and work on your algebra skills. If your algebra is good then, it is exactly the same with one difference. In algebra (A + -A) = 0, in Logic (A + A') = True. So when solving logic algebra whenever you see a term like that you can remove it from the equation.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically algebra.

Find common terms and move them outside and use parenthesis terms and try to find things that cancel out.

Try it, if you get stuck edit your question above and show what your current calculations are and someone might help you see where you went astray.

Comment: Anyway, the easiest method to verify is the truth table, really. Takes 15 seconds.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you are assuming the OP has covered truth tables yet.

Comment: @Trevor How can one deal with boolean algebra without TTs? How will you explain what basic operations are doing? By handwaving? No, you will give them the table describing it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes I would say you are right. I thought I saw the OP ask "What is a truth table?" in the comments before.. but that seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But it is quite simple to do logic as an extension of algebra without ever knowing about tables too. So who knows...

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat How will you describe what `NOT` is doing (formally)? I think we have different understanding what is walking and what is running... I want to see a syllabus of such a course.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's not that complicated, you end up with things like this... A(C' + C(B + B')) .. but you know (B + B') = True so that term disappears.

Comment: @Trevor I know how to do the Boolean algebra, I am pretty good at it :) I am just saying that verifying a known answer is simple with TT.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yup you are right. No arguments here. That's why some bright spark invented them. Ludwig Wittgenstein in case you are wondering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein

Comment: Or is it Emil Leon Post ..

Comment: I am pretty sure it is way older. It just wasn't widely published/formalized..

Comment: Yup, wrong guy gets the credit as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Logic 101 in Philosophy and Logic Design 101 for Electronics share the same Boolean Algebra Laws.

There's only about 10 of them and they are pretty simple,  Logic Rules were "invented" or documented by Aristotle then converted to Math symbols by Boole.

e.g.

- A(B + C) = A.B + A.C  ..............  (OR Distributive Law)
- A + (B.C) = (A + B).(A + C)   ... (AND Distributive Law)

  - dot or no dot = AND
  - while + = OR
  - NOT depends on user font, such as ... Not\$ \ A = A! =  \_A = \overline A\$

These are essential to learn to comprehend logic.

But you do the math!

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html

Answer (score -3):

Simple:

\$ A \overline C + ABC + A\overline BC = A \overline C + A(B+\overline B)C = A\overline C + AC = A(\overline C+C) = A. \$

Comment: Pat on the head for working out the answer. Slap on the back of the head for doing the kids homework for him...